# Profiling python code with valgrind produces empty log file

Tags: python, roslaunch, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am running 12 ROS nodes (ROS kinetic) and starting the system with a roslaunch file. I would like to profile one of the nodes, while the whol system is running. From my search it seems that I can use valgrind.

I set the roslaunch file as below ([as shown here](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/Tutorials/Profiling%20roslaunch%20nodes)):

```
<launch>
<param name="use_sim_time" value="true"/>
<arg name="seedval"/>
<param name="seed" value="$(arg seedval)"/>

<group ns="robot1">
<node pkg="pkg_name" name="agent" type="agent.py" launch-prefix="valgrind --tool=callgrind --separate-threads=yes --callgrind-out-file='callgrind.sim1.%p'">
<param name="myID" value="1"/>
......
</node>
</group>

.....
</launch>
```

I build the package in debug mode like so:

```
catkin_make -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
```

Now from what I have read, valgrind will dump the data when the program terminates. And the issue might lie here, because the nodes exit with sys.exit(), raising a SystemExit exception. I have tried adding the --dump-before=function option, but to no avail:

```
launch-prefix="valgrind --tool=callgrind --dump-before=name_of_function_as_in_script --separate-threads=yes --callgrind-out-file='callgrind.sim1.%p'"
```

Any ideas, I am not quite sure how to proceed.

Thanks!

hW

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/347638/profiling-python-code-with-valgrind-produces-empty-log-file/) by [highWaters](https://answers.ros.org/users/25790/highwaters/) on ROS Answers with karma: 176 on 2020-03-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2020-03-27**:
Do you mean you don't have the file `~/.ros/callgrind.sim1.PID_NUMBER` ?

Also I'm not sure that vallgrind can be used with python as it's said in the introduction of the tutorial :

> This tutorial explains how to use profiling tools for roscpp nodes that you are launching with roslaunch.

**Comment by [highWaters](https://answers.ros.org/users/25790/highwaters/) on 2020-03-27**:
Hi, I get the file, but it is empty. [From here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20112989/how-to-use-valgrind-with-python) it seems I might have to do compile python itself in debug mode, such that it is valgrind friendly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, I had an epiphany and did the following: `launch-prefix="pprofile --format callgrind --out out"`. I will marked this as solved.

---

Originally posted by [highWaters](https://answers.ros.org/users/25790/highwaters/) with karma: 176 on 2020-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1